# shift names of list up one level

Tags: r

I have a list of named elements that I want to transform into a named list of those elements:

```
el1 = c(a = 1)
el2 = c(b = 2)

b = list(el1, el2)
```

What I want is something like `a = list(a = 1, b = 2)`

so that `identical(a, b)` returns `TRUE`

Is there a transformation I can apply to `b` to do this? I tried a combination of unlist/unname but didn't seem like that got my any closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.list` after concatenating the `named` vectors

```
b <- as.list(c(el1, el2))
b
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] 2


identical(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Also, if the `list` is already created as in the OP's post, `unlist` and use `as.list`

```
b <- list(el1, el2)
b <- as.list(unlist(b))
identical(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am starting with `b`, any way to make `b` identical to `a` without accessing the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option, but not as simple as [the solution by akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63927316/12158757)

```
> do.call(c,Map(as.list,b))
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2
```